# How to Implement a if clause when the result of a calculation is less then zero

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case, workbench

THE CODE I AM WORKING IS:

```
UPDATE `tab_base_asset` 
INNER JOIN `vw_calcula_taxa_adm_ymf_acumulada_3` 
    ON `tab_base_asset`.`codigo_fundo` = `vw_calcula_taxa_adm_ymf_acumulada_3`.`codigo_fundo`
SET `tab_base_asset`.`RECEITA_ADM_YMF` = (`tab_base_asset`.`saldo_bruto_cdc`/`vw_calcula_taxa_adm_ymf_acumulada_3`.`saldo_bruto_cdc`) * `vw_calcula_taxa_adm_ymf_acumulada_3`.`receita_YMF_ACUM`, 
    `tab_base_asset`.`RECEITA_REBATE` = (`tab_base_asset`.`saldo_bruto_cdc`/`vw_calcula_taxa_adm_ymf_acumulada_3`.`saldo_bruto_cdc`) * `vw_calcula_taxa_adm_ymf_acumulada_3`.`Rebate_acumulado`
WHERE `tab_base_asset`.`data` = (SELECT `tab_aux_datas_base_unica`.`data_final` FROM `tab_aux_datas_base_unica`);
```

I would like to make the column `receita_adm_ymf` to become 0 for values which are less then 0.

I have got some syntax errors when using IF on My SQL Workbench 5.2 I also tried Case but I am not sure where to place it in the code.

Comment: When you have long table names, your queries will be much easier to read and write if you use aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GREATEST()` function to assign the max of the expression value and zero.

```
SET `tab_base_asset`.`RECEITA_ADM_YMF` = GREATEST(0, (`tab_base_asset`.`saldo_bruto_cdc`/`vw_calcula_taxa_adm_ymf_acumulada_3`.`saldo_bruto_cdc`) * `vw_calcula_taxa_adm_ymf_acumulada_3`.`receita_YMF_ACUM`),
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar when proceeding with your instruction I found that what a really need is to use the CEILING command as I need to round upper the generated value after the calculations, this a field issue which results in a truncated error, it is like a division of 5/ 333531308, which results a very small number that 1,49911E-08 that is not supported by the field size, do you have any other ideia?

Comment: I don't think division of positive numbers should ever produce a negative result, even if it's very tiny.